# How to define child routes as react components in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have `main.js`:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import Home from './containers/Home';
import ApplicationsRoutes from './applications/routes';

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component="div">
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />      
      <ApplicationsRoutes />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

And `/application/routes.js` :

```
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import ApplicationsHome from './containers/ApplicationsHome';

export default () => (
  <Route path="applications" component={ApplicationsHome} />
);
```

I was expecting that route from `/application/routes.js` will be added to the main router and so ApplicationsHome will be rendered for path `/applications`

Unfortunately, this is not a case. I am getting error:

```
Location "/applications" did not match any routes
```

For me it looks like such a way to compose Router does not work, but I cannot understand what is right way to do this.

Comment: Have you looked at following [React Router Examples](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples) ?
Covers lot of scenarios to understand its working.

Comment: @WitVault yep, they have example `huge-apps` which is about the same functionality, however it does not use react composition. So it will work as workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For singular routes you can export your route as a JSX element:

```
export default <Route path="applications" component={ApplicationsHome} />;
```

And include it like this:

```
{SomeRoute}
```

For multiple routes you can't export them as you have in a function, you'll get a JSX error saying you can't have adjacent components without a wrapping element. In that case you would have to do:

```
export default (
  <Route>
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
  </Route>
);
```

And use it:

```
{ApplicationsRoutes}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @taion, didn't realise you could do it that way, much better. Also left in `ReactRouter` for some jsfiddle testing

Answer (score 3):

In general, when you do this, you should consider using the `PlainRoute` syntax instead of the JSX syntax, then use `getChildRoutes` on the parent routes to resolve the child routes, per the huge-apps example: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps

This will then let you easily configure code-splitting and dynamic routes down the road.